# Referer website in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

Hello I'm trying to get referral website and insert it into my database .

What I want is to get the referral site which called my "jsp page" before its posted into Servlet

For instance I have first.jsp which I reach from "www.example.com"

When I POST data from first into servlet I want to get the "www.example.com" but not "first.jsp"

When I do this in my servlet, I get "first.jsp"

```
request.getHeader("referer")
```

Comment: how do I get the referrer site not the referrer jsp page that got me into the servlet...sorry I havnt made it clear

Comment: may be it is because you are reffering from same domain, try to link from other web app and see what it shows

Comment: hmm maybe I didnt make myself clear enough, the servlet is giving me previous page which is my own page, not the website that lead to the previous page

Comment: You would have to put that code in the jsp <%String referer = request.getHeader("referer"); %> and then pass that into the Servlet as a parameter

Comment: Yay for you Dan, yes thats what I meant!! sorry I sounded a bit noob but thats what I exactly meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it

in the jsp page I placed this code

```
<%  session.setAttribute("Referer",request.getHeader("Referer")); %>
```

Now in java servlet I used this code

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
String referrer = session.getAttribute("Referer").toString();
```